# Windows file API to create nameless temporary files

Tags: windows, file, file-io, temporary-files

On Linux my application creates a temporary file using *mkstemp()* and does immediately deletes the name from the file system using *unlink()*. So when the *fd* is closed the file is deleted and space is freed.
These APIs make the code very simple.

I want to do the same thing in Windows. Even though Windows has *_unlink()* function it does not delete the file from the file system if *fd* is open.
Is there another Windows API to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Windows has different file system semantics.  You can't have a nameless file.  However, you can specify the FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE flag so that the file will be deleted when you're done with it without having to do so explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good workaround for Windows. But something to keep in mind is NtCreateFile() which takes FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE option is an internal API. So it might not be a compatible solution.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I meant `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`.  They do the same thing, but `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` is for NtCreateFile() and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` is for CreateFile().

Comment: Thanks! For sake of completeness would add that _open() call also seems to take O_TEMPORARY flag which does the same.